# ¿Cómo usar variables globales en python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Verán quisiera saber como hacer para que las funciones que utilizo en python tomen el valor de las variables globales, y como hago para que esas variables conserven el valor que les asigno en las funciones.
Por ejemplo: Tengo la variable "decisión" para saber qué opción quiere realizar el usuario. En la función de activar yo le doy un nuevo valor a decisión, pero no conserva ese valor, entonces quisiera saber cómo se manejan las variables globales.
PD: Ya probé utilizando global y me da error para modificar:

```
def entrada():
    global comienzo
    comienzo = 1
    neurona(comienzo)
    return comienzo
```

PD: comienzo la defino desde arriba ya que su valor se edita con las opciones seleccionadas por el usuario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varios modos de manejar variables "globales", voy a enumerar unos cuantos:

1. Usar un diccionario: Los diccionarios son elementos mutables y pueden ser leídos y modificados dentro de las funciones.
2. Usar una clase:

Una clase vacia es equivalente a un diccionario, mas o menos

```
class Variables:
    pass
variables = Variables()
```

los elementos que recoja la clase pueden ser usados en todo el modulo

```
variables.a = 1
def cambiavariables():
    variables.a = variables.a + variables.a
print(variables.a)
cambiavariables()
print(variables.a)
cambiavariables()
print(variables.a)
```

3. Guardar las variables en un modulo e importarlas:

En variables.py

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

en cualquier otro modulo:

```
import variables
print(variables.a) # da 1
variables.a = 3 # cambia el valor para todos los sitios donde se importe variables.py
```

La ventaja de este modo es que el cambio se mueve entre modulos ahorrando por ejemplo tener que pasar variables a funciones.

4. Usar global:

usar global te permite usar variables en las funciones, pero hay que declararlo en cada funcion

```
a = 1
def sumame():
    global a
    a = a + 1
for i in range(5):
    sumame()
    print(a)
```

Espero que te ayude

Answer (score 2):

En principio solo debes **declarar las variables fuera de la funcion** y luego hacer uso de ellas mediante la palabra reservada global (como haces en tu código, solo que te falta definirla fuera).

Tu código rehecho con una muestra:

```
comienzo = 0 #declaro la variable fuera de las funciones

def entrada():
    global comienzo #uso de la variable como global
    comienzo = 1
    neurona(comienzo)
    return comienzo

entrada()
print(comienzo) # aqui la variable contiene 1
```

Espero que te sirva.